# +[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:] Literal?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnumber, unsigned-integer, objective-c-literals

I know I can do `@3` instead of `[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]`
 but what's the literal for `[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:3]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typecasting also works if you do not remember the correct literal.

```
NSNumber* number = @((NSUInteger)3);
```

Comment: `+numberWithUnsignedInteger:` takes `NSUInteger`, not `unsigned int`. I have edited your post to reflect that.

Comment: Actually, this seems better than @3u because it's correct on both Mac & iOS, whereas adding u as a suffix is only correct for iOS, not Mac (ul). Correct?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `@3U` or `@3UL` (or use the usual integer suffixes to change the type, e.g. `@3ULL` for `unsigned long long`).

See [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html) for more information on NSNumber literals.

Comment: Looks like you can also do lowercase suffixes, e.g., @3u, according to Xcode Docs : Programming with Objective-C : Values and Collections.

Answer (score 2):

`@3UL` will give you an `NSNumber` that is explicitly the same width/signedness as an `NSUInteger`.

But ask yourself *why* you want this? Since `3` is representable exactly by *all* numeric types in C/Objective-C<sup>1</sup>, `@3` gives you an object that behaves identically. Although the type of the constant used is different, the object you get can be used in all the same ways and can be unboxed with the same set of methods.

<sup>1</sup> Okay, okay, excepting types that represent only 1 bit such as `_Bool` and `int : 1`.

Comment: Actually, 3 is not representable by a 1 wide bit-field, FYI.

Comment: Is `_Bool` a numeric type? I'm quite sure conversion rules for `_Bool` ensure it only holds 0 or 1.

Comment: @dreamlax Okay, okay, modifying my answer. Pedants.

Comment: I'm only teasing :) your answer has a valid point, but perhaps `3UL` is not the only unsigned integer requiring boxing.

Comment: @dreamlax: They all require boxing to be used as an `NSNumber`, but worrying about the type of the primitive is generally silly since `NSNumber` will convert losslessly wherever possible.

Comment: UL is for Mac. U is for iPhone. Correct?

Comment: Nope. UL is always appropriate.

Comment: Really? Have you looked at the latest definition of `NSUInteger`?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: You misunderstand. One will generate an `unsigned long` while the other will just generate an `unsigned int`. But *it doesn't matter* because the primitive type of the value is abstracted away by `NSNumber`, which then can be asked for any numeric type you need. You only need to worry if the value cannot be represented by both primitive types.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: If you're referring to the definition of `NSUInteger` as `unsigned int` on some targets, it's still moot because `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are explicitly identical types under the relevant ABIs, so supplying a value of one type to a function/etc. expecting the other is safe/free.

Comment: OK. To be safe (& explicit), I prefer to just cast as `NSUInteger` as @Davyd suggests.

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: Actually, Davyd's suggestion won't give you a compile-time constant, it'll give you a runtime box. But otherwise, it's not really going to make a difference.